# MySQL row data to PHP array key/value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So I'm trying to integrate a bit of Wordpress with a backend. Their MySQL schema isn't too great, especially when you add in Woocommerce.

I've come up with the following query:

```
SELECT wp.* 
FROM   wp_postmeta wp
       INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id 
                   FROM   wp_postmeta
                   WHERE  ( `meta_key` = '_shipping_method' 
                            AND `meta_value` = 'free_shipping' ) 
                           OR ( `meta_key` = '_order_items' 
                                AND `meta_value` LIKE '%search%' )) a 
               ON a.post_id = wp.post_id 
ORDER  BY wp.post_id DESC
```

To be run on this table https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMHQp.jpg to select the right things for certain people.

Now when I var_dump this in PHP it comes out like so (truncated) - http://pastebin.com/WR3byT8k

Is there any way I can map this properly to an array so that I can use something simple like:

```
echo $content['_billing_first_name']; 
echo $content['_billing_last_name'];
```

Which would output: 
`John`
`Citizen`

Keep in mind all the content is dynamic, so I can't just use row numbers.

Comment: I've just posted a snip of the output, but yeah its weird. Here's my code - http://pastebin.com/pxdcJNni

Comment: For one, `mysql_fetch_assoc` rather than `mysql_fetch_array`. It seems like the easiest way to accomplish what you want is to do a `GROUP BY` followed by looping over each result, merging the arrays.

Comment: E-Commerce with WordPress? What a database disaster.

Comment: Right you are njk. @jli how do you propose I `GROUP BY`? I can't see any obvious solution...

Comment: Off topic, but to avoid the shitstorm that is Wordpress eCommerce, I suggest taking a look at Shopify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed set of meta keys you need to retrieve (not necessarily a fixed order), you can do it in the query itself by using a technique similar to a pivot table.

```
SELECT 
  post_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_billing_first_name' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS _billing_first_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_billing_last_name' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS _billing_last_name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_some_other_attribute' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS _some_other_attribute,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key = '_another_attribute' THEN meta_value ELSE NULL END) AS _another_attribute,
  ...
  ...
FROM wp_post_meta
GROUP BY post_id
```

The `CASE` statements determine which parameter you are pulling and assign it to a column.  They are wrapped in `MAX()` aggregates simply to eliminate the NULLs which result when the keys don't match, collapsing it down to a single row with columns for each attribute rather than multiple rows with mostly NULL values.

Failing this (if your set of attributes is varies unexpectedly), you would need to iterate in code. That would be messy though.

#### In PHP:

Using PHP, if you have an array of the meta post keys you want to retrieve, you can loop over all rows and if the `meta_key` is one you want, store the `meta_value` onto an array:

```
// Assumes your WP query results are already stored into the array $your_db_rows

// Will hold your final processed results
$output = array();
// If you want only a specific set of meta_key names rather than all meta_key names
$keys_you_want = array('_billing_first_name','_billing_last_name','_some_other_attribute');

// Loops over the result set
foreach ($your_db_rows_array as $row) {
  // If the current row holds one of the meta_key you are looking for
  if (in_array($row['meta_key'], $keys_you_want)) {
    // Put it onto the output array using the meta_key as the array key
    $output[$row['meta_key'] = $row['meta_value'];
  }
  // Otherwise do nothing...
}
var_dump($output);
```

To get all `meta_key`, just leave out the `in_array()` test and the `$keys_you_want` array. That will store every `meta_key` encountered onto `$output`.

```
// Loops over the result set for all values of meta_key, not a specific set
foreach ($your_db_rows_array as $row) {
  // Put it onto the output array using the meta_key as the array key
  $output[$row['meta_key'] = $row['meta_value'];
}
var_dump($output);
```

Comment: Ideally I need to be able to access any of the data within the rows under meta_keys... I'm wondering how Woocommerce do it in the first place heh.

Comment: @Dean As long as you know what possible key values are present in `meta_keys`, you can list them all using this method.

Comment: I understand and this will use whatever is in `meta_value` then too?

Comment: @Dean Yes - meta_key and meta_value are both columns in the same row. This matches the value of meta_key for each attr you want, and returns the meta_value for that row.  In the end, you should get only one row per post_id based on the `GROUP BY`, with as many columns as you have matched attrs for.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This seems like the only logical solution for now. I've also sent an email off to the devs of the lovely plugin to see what they can shed some light on. Thanks again.

Comment: Is there any other way in PHP you could get these details without screwing around with too much SQL?

Comment: In PHP you could loop over all rows with an array of the attributes you are looking for, and do basically the same thing. if the meta_key matches the attribute in the current loop iteration, store the meta_value. I'll add it above...

Comment: perhaps you could fix up the code on the PHP one as I only have a rough idea on what you're trying to do. The SQL one isn't what I want really, because it is very cumbersome.

Comment: @Dean I put in a bunch more comments.